# Правопис і абетка. Чи всі варіанти припустимі?

Tags: discussion, nonstandard-grammar

Ми всі певною мірою вільно інтерпретуємо чинний правопис, іноді відходимо від нього на якусь дистанцію, бо аж надто нелоґічними й пострадянськими здаються нам деякі його норми.

Більшість з нас, водночас, не забуває про те, що на цей сайт заходять звичайні користувачі та хочуть дізнатися відповідь на питання, а не розбиратися, що ж це за такі знаки написав той чи інший дописувач.

Тому конкретизую питання:

1. Чи припустимо писати літерами, яких немає в українській абетці?

Приклад: ӝерела, „Ӓк ми говоримо“

"ӝерело": https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/3790/240

2. Чи припустимо питати українською мовою, і при цьому латинкою?

Приклад був у коментарях під цим постом: [Чи є синоніми до слова "пак"?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3809/240), але модератор вже видалив ті коментарі, бо НЕ українська мова неприйнятна на цьому сайті, тож надаю приклад з чату: "Zroblü perebukvynyšü z poäsnüvannäm i dodam do opysu osobiwky." Ладно ще ми тут з мовою граємося, знаємо умляути, але я версії 2010 року просто пішов би з сайту миттєво, бо "тут зібралися якісь фріки, що їх слухати з приводу мови?"

(Я особисто за введення в Україні паралельної латинки, але до офіційного рішення та імплементації не хочу навіть чути про це на сайті, особливо у тому вигляді, який бачимо вище)

Якщо це неприпустимо, то пропоную змушувати дописувачів переписувати свої дописи або видаляти/редаґувати ті дописи самостійно через те, що це НЕ українська мова. Буду радий почути думку інших.

Comment: Думаю, це питання вже було зрушене кілька разів (див. за тегом [nonstandard-grammar](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nonstandard-grammar). Особисто я частково погоджуюся з фактичним матеріалом, який викладений у цьому запитанні, але його тон балансує на межі rant.

Comment: А по суті, з точки зору правил SE, відповідь одна: (1) дописи **можуть бути** написані будь-яким діалектом української; (2) відповіді **бажано** дописувати тим діалектом, яким дописане запитання; (3) кожний користувач має невідʼємне **право мінусувати** будь-який допис з будь-яких причин, та ще й прокоментувати, що, мовляв, не розумію цього діалекту.

Comment: @bytebuster так це не діалект. Це просто інше написання, яке багатьом незрозуміле. Так відповіді нормальні, я їх плюсую, мене форма не влаштовує. Зміст - супер.

Comment: Tooltip під кнопкою downvote каже: «this answer is not useful […]». Якщо воно незрозуміле, то і not useful. Окрім того, SE задумувався як майданчик, де люди з різними поглядами можуть спільно створювати корисний контент. Тому не дуже очевидно, чесно кажучи, яким чином цей Meta Q може розвʼязати суперечку, у більшій мірі, ніж це зроблено у linked question.

Comment: Рідкий випадок, коли я згоден з bytebuster — це виглядає справді дублікатом старого питання. Але зауважте, я не наполягаю на своїй трактовці. Ви можете там окрему відповідь надати, мовляв, «я незгоден із § 3 іншої відповіді, я вважаю, що…» і далі наприклад «відповіді (навіть якщо вони стосуються нест. діалектів/правописів) мають надаватися у стандартному діалекті/правописі (нестандарт може бути лише в цитатах/прикладах)» — це відразу буде спроба вето і на «gerelo/ӝерело», і на «инші/варіянти» (або, якщо Ви хочете якось відділити одне від іншого, то якось відділити).

Comment: Як обирати потім серед двох відповідей — гадки не маю (голосуванням?) — але, по-моєму, Ви маєте право висловити власну думку.

Comment: Я не наполягаю, але моя позиція не дуже змінилася: б дозволяв би все (і навіть питати іншими мовами окрім укр. і англ., але це було окремо проголосовано «проти» і, здається, також є проти правил SE). Так, я згоден, що це виглядає по-фрицьки (від слова «фрик», а не від слова «фриць»), але, по-моєму, реальний вклад людини (а отже і її ентузіазм) важливіший за вигляд (і також треба віддати Follower належне, він пише латинкою лише коментарі, не відповіді).

Comment: Єдине, що мені не сподобалося в конкретній ситуації — це те, що Follower у своєму коментарі-у-відповідь просто дав користувачу посилання на свою таблицю транслітерації (по-моєму, це було якось не дуже ввічливо, я би написав коментар, хай навіть і відмову, стандартною українською чи англійською, мовляв, «вибачте, через такі-то переконання я не буду писати по-іншому, якщо Вас такі коментарі неприйнятні, то, значить, моя спроба допомогли була невдалою, будь ласка, зачекайте на коментарі від інших людей» — але це моє бачення, можливо, для когось це, навпаки, буде грубіше ніж посилання на таблицю).

Comment: Я вважаю що мова існує для того щоб люди розуміли одне одного. Коли один з учасників кожні декілька місяців все більше і більше віддаляється від загальних норм спілкування і розуміти його стає все складніше - то це вже ненормально. Я розумію коли є деякі орфоргафічні відмінності і можна зрозуміти людину трохи напружившись. Я розумію коли людина запитує з-за кордону і в неї тимчасово немає кириличної клавіатури. Але читаючи останні коментарі - треба мозок зламати щоб їх зрозуміти. Я вважаю що це занадто. Якщо пану Follower'у треба майданчик для практикування - він може знайти його деінде.